# Raid 1 rebuilding with Server 2008 r2 and two partitions on one drive

Tags: partitioning, raid, windows-server-2008

A client of ours has an older server.  I was not involved in the setup and don't usually get involved with servers but will probably be involved on this one. I recently had to reboot the system and saw via Intel Matrix Storage Manager (MSM, ver. 8.9.0.123) that the second drive showed an error.  The first drive appears to be fine. Anyway, from what I've seen, this server was configured with RAID 1 with two 500 GB hard drives.  The guy who configured the server split the drive into two partitions, one for the operating system (Server 2008 r2, ~150GB) and the other for office data (~315 GB).  I have the exact same model number of hard drive to use as a replacement for the second drive, but wanted to make sure of a couple of things as I've never done this before...

1. Is there much difference between the interface for Matrix Storage Manager and Rapid Storage Technology?  They look similar in the videos I've watched.
2. Is this as simple as turning off the server, replacing the bad drive with a good one, selecting the replacement drive for rebuilding via MSM, and exiting the MSM back to Windows?
3. Does it make a difference that I have two partitions on the hard drive?  Will the system just copy the two partitions on the mirror drive on its own or is there more involved?

I know many will think "just get a new server" but that's not an option at this stage.  And I'm just trying to be sure I'm doing this right so no data (and/or my job) gets lost in the process.